# Firebase Cloud Functions - Throw Auth Error

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

Is it possible to throw an Auth Error from HTTPs callble functions?

I mean, instead of this

```
 if (err.code === "auth/email-already-exists") {
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
      "invalid-argument",
      "The email address is already in use by other account"
    );
  }
```

something like

```
exports.signUp = functions
  .region("us-central1")
  .runWith({ memory: "2GB", timeoutSeconds: 120 })
   .https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
      ...

      if (err.code === "auth/email-already-exists") {
        throw err;
      }

      ...
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Callable Functions should return an instance of [`HttpsError`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/common_providers_https.httpserror) which requires [gRPC error codes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/common_providers_https#functionserrorcode) so the details of the error are properly transmitted to calling clients. If you throw a different error type, the client will only see a `HttpsError` with the code and message `"internal"` - no specifics will be sent to the client for safety.

If you want to pass through the error code of a Firebase Error, you can do so using the third argument. Also consider using `"failed-precondition"` (preferred) or `"already-exists"` (if it's a resource) instead.

```
if (err.code === "auth/email-already-exists") {
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
      "invalid-argument",
      "The email address is already in use by other account",
      { code: err.code }
    );
  }
```